# jQuery .load function not working in FF

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lightbox script which works fine in every browser except FF.

```
var img = $(this).children('img').clone();
        img.load(function () {
```

The .load function doesn't seem to be running.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you assign a src to the image after applying the load event? Otherwise it's unlikely for the load event to be bound before the load event happens.

Comment: Additionally, .load for binding to the load event was removed in jquery 1.9